# Manipulations with temp tables on the same connection don't work with sprocs

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a long-lived connection, on which the application creates a temp table and uses it to fetch some dynamic runtime data. To my understanding it should be possible to reference this temp table as long as it is done on the same connection. It is possible indeed when I do a bunch of raw queries, but it is not possible with sprocs. I use ADO.NET.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Works**

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerNames (CustomerName nvarchar(200) PRIMARY KEY)
DECLARE @CustomerName nvarchar(200)
SET @CustomerName ='Joe Baker'
INSERT INTO #CustomerNames (CustomerName) VALUES (@CustomerNames)
```

**Doesn't work**

```
EXEC customerNames_createTempTable
EXEC customerNames_addCustomerName 'Joe Baker'
```

where sprocs encapsulate the queries

**EDIT**: the solution is to create a temp table outside of a sproc using a query and then do all the manipulations with the table on the same connection using sprocs. This way the temp table doesn't go out of scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked with SQL Server, but as far as I know, temporary tables created within stored procedure only exist for the duration of the procedure execution. In other words, they are dropped when the procedure is finished.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to creating a temp table that could be used within the same connection and referenced between sprocs? I dont want to use global temp tables.

Comment: @kateroh Maybe create a wrapper sproc which creates the temp table? This way all called sprocs are in scope.

Comment: @Ocaso actually the temp table cannot be created within a sproc as it will be out of scope the moment sproc is executed. The solution is to create a table using a query and then use sprocs for manipulations with the table.

Comment: @kateroh I think you misunderstood me, I will  try to rephrase it. What I mean is that you should execute `EXEC customerNames_addCustomerName 'Joe Baker'` (or any other sproc) inside of `customerNames_createTempTable`. But that will lead to a lot of code duplication, as you have to do this for every call you need the temp table for.
But if your solution works it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the scope of validity of the temp tables. A temp table only exists inside the stored proc that creates the table and inside all the stored procs the first sproc is calling. So in your not working example the temp table is invalid after you call `customerNames_createTempTable`.

A solution is a global temp table. These temp tables are created with '#', e.g. ##CustomerNames. But beware: Global temporary tables are visible to all SQL Server connections. So you have to name them with a unique name.

BTW: It is good habit to explicitly drop the temp tables when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: You could create the temp table with raw SQL and then use it in a proc couldn't you?  It would really help to know more about the reason why the asker was wanting to do it...

Comment: Well, global temp tables (or variables) tend to have side effects, e.g. another sproc can modify the temp table to, witch lead to unwanted to results. So it's normaly good to avoid them. When you use a unique naming schema (e.g. name+guid) you end up in dynamic sql very fast.

Comment: @Jason thats what i ended up doing - creating the table with raw sql. thanks!